# Removing oldest inserted data from sorted list

Tags: c#

I have a List of objects that expands over time as more and more data gets added to it but will have a fixed maximum size at some point.

```
public class Calculation 
{
  public List<DataUnit> DataUnits { get; set; } = new();

  public void AddSorted(DataUnit unit)
  {
    int index = DataUnits.BinarySearch(unit);
    DataUnits.Insert((index>=0) x : ~x, unit);
  }

  public void AddData(DataUnit unit)
  {
    AddSorted(unit);
    if(DataUnits.Count > 30)
    {
      // i need some sort of solution here
      DataUnits.RemoveOldest();
    }
  }

  public void SomeCalculation()
  {
    // performs some calculation, that is O(1) with a sorted list and O(N) with a non sorted list
  }
    
}
```

The catches are restrictions to performance, RAM and time.
The actual code (not the dummy one above), will have a lot of data coming in (something around 1000-2000 dataunits) within a 1 second time frame on a limited ressources machine.
We have to perform calculations on this list, which is just way faster to do on a sorted list. And, since new data will be coming in each second, all the calculations have to be done within a second.

What would be the most optimal way of implementing this?

I thought about either sorting the list before each calculation separately, but I am afraid that O(sqrt(n)) will just not cut it.
My second Idea would be a second list, that just preserves the time of insertion sorting, but with a lot of data, I think we might hit a resource limit when holding two list of those dataunits.

**// EDIT**

Additional Information about the DataUnit

```
public class DataUnit : IComparable
{
  public IComparable Data { get; set; }
  public int CompareTo(object? o)
  {
    if(o is DataUnit other)
    {
      return Data.CompareTo(other.Data);
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

**Properties about the Calculation**
the `SomeCalculation` method performs an intensiv calculation over all the present data. This calculation only works with a sorted list by its Property `Data` (some index math magic, not important here).

So in the end, the List `DataUnits` must be sorted by `Data`. Since we have a lot more calls of `SomeCalculation` then `AddData` my implementation uses a list with sorted insertion rather than sorting the list every time we call `SomeCalculation`.

Problem: The `DataUnits` List reaches a fixed size (for example 30 elements), and will preserve its size after that. If one element gets added to the list, the **oldest** DataUnit object should be removed (and therefore not included in the calculation)

Comment: Does the list always contain not more than 30 elements? Will the AddSorted be called not from AddData? How often is SomeCalculation called in comparison to AddData?

Comment: Is each `DataUnit` in the list unique according to the key that you order it by? (I assume that `DataUnit` implements `IComparable<DataUnit>`.) Your current `AddSorted()` is an O(N) operation (due to `List.Insert()` being O(N) other than at the end of the list) and a sorted hashing container could improve that to O(Log(N))

Comment: `I think we might hit a resource limit when holding two list of those dataunits.` Don't forget that if `DataUnit` is a reference type, then only a reference is stored for each item in the list. Since you are worried about RAM usage I assume you're running 32-bit code, so it would only require 32 bits for each item in the list.

Comment: Have you checked this? A ConcurrentQueue, Represents a thread-safe first in-first out (FIFO) collection.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-6.0

Comment: @ciamej 30 is arbitrary, but the list is fixed size, yes

@ MatthewWatson DataUnits are unique in it self, but  the IComparable interface is not depended on the key, but a different data property (eg Temperature)
The Insert is allowed to take some time, the intention was to have a bit of an overhead in the Adding of elements instead of the Calculation Method (by sorting the array then)
Good point about the reference, RAM might not be a problem in the end

@ MaheshBongani A Queue wouldn't solve the problem, because I need a sorted list for my Calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the performance of `SomeCalculation` is indeed the most important, and additional overhead in `AddData` is acceptable, then your approach is ok. Keep the list sorted at all times, do not sort it each time you perform  `SomeCalculation`.

To remove the oldest element: keep a fixed-size queue of `DataUnit` (these are references), besides inserting the new element to the sorted list, add it to the end of the queue. If the queue size exceeds the intended size, remove one element from the front of the queue, then search for it in the sorted list and remove it from the list.

Searching for an element to be removed can be done using binary search, but removing it from the sorted list is `O(n)`, but so is inserting a new element in the middle of the list, so the performance is similar.

You could actually remove the old element and insert the new one in one pass of the sorted list, to slightly improve performance, but I wouldn't go for it, as the gains for a small list will be marginal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but according to MSDN List.Add appends element to the end of the list. Wouldn't be easiest to simply Add elements (which will always go to the end), count their numbers and once it reaches threshol remove first one? (aka the oldest one?) Of course this expects you do not change order of elements in the list. Something like cyclic buffer.

Something like this:

```
public void AddData(DataUnit unit)
{
   DataUnits.Add(unit);
   if (DataUnits.Count() > 30)
   {
      DataUnits.RemoveAt(0);
   }
}
```

Edit:
Mathew Watson comment made me think a little bit. I believe this way you can have sorted array and remove last element:

```
  public class Calculation 
  {
    private DataUnit lastElement = null;

    public List<DataUnit> DataUnits { get; set; } = new();

    public void AddSorted(DataUnit unit)
    {
      int index = DataUnits.BinarySearch(unit);
      DataUnits.Insert((index>=0) x : ~x, unit);
    }

    public void AddData(DataUnit unit)
    {
      AddSorted(unit);

      // you don't need to use LINQ, you may test it against Count
      if (DataUnits.Any() == false)
      {
        this.lastElement = unit;
      }

      if(DataUnits.Count > 30)
      {
        if (this.lastElement != null)
        {
          DataUnits.Remove(this.lastElement);
          this.lastElement = unit;
        }
      }
    }
```

because all you need to know is that between some element and 30th element were 30 additions (and no removal). So all you need to do is to remember current element, count 30 additions and then remove that element and the one you're adding will be new candidate for removal.

Comment: But then it wouldn't be sorted.

Comment: Yes and that's the part I did not get. He needs sorting because he wants to find oldest element (aka it is a part of try to be efficient in removing last element) or container being sorted is essential part of what's he is doing and it would do it either way and it is independent of his tries to remove last element? If the second is correct, how does he define "last" element? lastly added element? or last in the list (which is not the same) or something else?

Comment: I think they need two ordering: Ordered by `DataUnit` (however that implements `IComparable<DataUnit>`) for the algorithm and ordered by insertion order to remove the oldest elements.

Comment: I will update my question accordingly to make the problem more clearly.
Your solution, however elegant, is not the solution to my problem ;)